# Query parameter setting with Swagger

Tags: python, python-3.x, django-rest-framework, swagger, drf-yasg

How can I change the `required fields` (`address`, `token_id`, etc) to not be required like `limit` and `offset` in swagger?

This is specific for `GET` requests

model

```
class NFT(models.Model):
    address = models.CharField(max_length=42)
    owner_address = models.CharField(max_length=42)
    token_id = models.IntegerField()
    token_URI = models.URLField()
    name = models.CharField(max_length=256)
```

serializer

```
class NFTSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = NFT
        fields = [
            "address",
            "owner_address",
            "token_id",
            "token_URI",
            "name",
        ]
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since drf-yasg follows the serializer definition, you can add `required=False` in the serializer

```
class NFTSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    address = serializers.CharField(required=False)
    token_id = serializers.IntegerField(required=False)

    class Meta:
        model = NFT
        fields = [
            "address",
            "owner_address",
            "token_id",
            "token_URI",
            "name",
        ]
```

Comment: Getting `TypeError: Field.__init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'required'` =/

Comment: sorry, should be serializer.CharField instead of models.CharField. I'll edit the answer.